# ASP.NET Cache and Output Cache for Controls

Tags: asp.net, sql, caching, outputcache, webusercontrol

You know I have the way to Cache the data I've got from the SQL Server over data caching. In addition I can output cache web user controls.

**Whats about a web user control contains data from a SQL database? Does it make sense to cache the data and also cache the control?**

**What is the best solution for the combination of these two components?**

*Yes. this is a newbie question.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cache the control, then you don't need to cache the underlying data.
Optimal caching, as always, depends on your application.

Here are some general guidelines:

Use data caching for complex, CPU/Memory intensive queries, for data that is used very often on different pages/controls.

Use output caching for controls that appear often.  Output caching also tends to be simpler to implement compared to data caching with requires more thought concerning threading/locking, etc.